# Manipulate store values

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

Is there a way to store the numerical values from a manipulate function in the form of a table? For example, if the function is

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 2x
```

Can one store all the values for each value of `x` in `(0,1)` from `Manipulate[]` other than taking a snapshot?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to store.

Comment: He wants to `Append` every value of the given mononomials / after decomposition of the function / to a table.

Comment: If you can explain more. Do you mean you can to change x using a slider and have all the function values stored in a list for each x value changed. Then you want to click on a button to see the collected list?

Comment: @Nasser He wants to decompose the polynomial and for every value of `x`, linked to the slider, to store the corresponding value of every mononomial in a table.

Answer (score 3):

There are infinite numbers between 0 and 1. Perhaps you want to memoize a finite subset of them.

Move the slider produced by the following code.

```
Manipulate[f[x] = x^2-2x, {x, 0, 1, .01}]
```

After that, run `?? f` and you will get the values that were "stored".

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[f]; f[x_] := f[x] = x^2 - 2 x
Manipulate[f[s], {s, 0, 1}]
Dynamic@Thread[{(Most@DownValues@f)[[All, 1, 
     1]] , (Most@DownValues@f)[[All, 2]]}]
```